# Erro em Class no Python

Tags: python, classes

Criei o código abaixo porém está me dando erro:

> ```
> Pessoa = Empregados('joao')
> TypeError: Empregados() takes no arguments.
> ```

O que eu posso ter feito de errado?

```
class Empregados:
    def __int__(self, nome, email, skype):
        self.nome = str(nome)
        self.email = str(email)
        self.skype = str(skype)

    def mostrar(self):
        print(self.nome, self.email, self.skype)
empr = Empregados('Joao', 'exemplo@gmail.com', 'Joao.vitor')
empr.mostrar()
```

Comment: O nome do método é `__init__`, e não `__int__`. De qualquer forma, fazer apenas `Empregados('joao')` também vai dar erro porque vc também precisa passar o email e o skype

Comment: entendi, deu certo, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Corrija o nome do método de inicialização da classe, o correto é `__init__`

```
class Empregados:
    def __init__(self, nome, email, skype):
        self.nome = str(nome)
        self.email = str(email)
        self.skype = str(skype)
```

para chamar a classe o correto é assim:

```
variavel = Classe(atributo='valor')
```

no seu caso:

```
pessoa = Empregados(nome='joao', email='example@example.com', skype='joao')
```

Outra dica:

você não precisa usar str se o email, nome e skype já vier como string ;)